# Как сделать, чтобы кнопка routeButtonControl автоматически раскрывалась и строился маршрут?

Tags: яндекс-карты

По этому коду должен строится маршрут:

```js
ymaps.geolocation.get({
                    autoReverseGeocode: false,
                    mapStateAutoApply: true
                }).then(function(result) {
                    var control = myMap.controls.get('routeButtonControl');
                    var office_id = onMapMarks[a].getAttribute('office-id');
                    // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
                    control.routePanel.state.set({
                        // Тип маршрутизации.
                        type: 'masstransit',
                        // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
                        fromEnabled: true,
                        // Адрес или координаты пункта отправления.
                        from: result.geoObjects.position,
                        // Включим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
                        toEnabled: true,
                        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
                        to: data['offices'][office_id]['coord'].map(Number)
                    });
                });
```

Маршрут строится, но только тогда, когда нажимаешь на кнопку "Маршруты". Как сделать, чтобы кнопка автоматически раскрывалась и строился маршрут?
То есть нужно чтобы кнопка из такой:
[image: кнопка маршруты]
Превращалась в такую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

После описания переменной button достаточно добавить поле состояния state:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.Button-docpage/

```
button.state.set('selected', true);
```